# Como criar uma pasta no php e logo após lançar exec?

Tags: php

Preciso criar uma pasta e logo após lançar a thumbnail criada nela.

```
mkdir(pasta, 0777. true);

if(a pasta recém criada existir ){
   exec("ffmpeg -i ".$currentPath." -vf fps=1/60 " .$pasta_recem_criada."/thumb%03d.png", $output, $return);
}
```

Comment: `if (is_dir("caminho/da/pasta") === true || is_file("caminho/da/pasta") === true) { exec() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o próprio retorno da função `mkdir` para verificar se a pasta foi criada. Ex:

```
<?php

$folderClip = "clip";
$folderVideos = "~/Videos"

/**
 * Tenta criar a pasta, caso a pasta seja criada
 * retorna `true` e então executa a função `exec`
 * caso contrário, "pula" o código.
 */
if (mkdir($pasta, 0777, true)) {
    exec("ffmpeg -i {$folderVideos}/papa_mike.mp4 -vframes 1 {$folderClip}/papa_mike.png", $output, $return);
}
```

> Obs.: Caso seu arquivo esteja na raiz do projeto, não é necessário passar a pasta atual.